# C# Specifying different algorithms/logic flow in configuration file

Tags: c#

I would like to specify the functionality of an application in a json file that is passed to the application. This will be used to load different libraries.

For example a dictionary containing:

```
"RunType1" : {
    "Init" : "AlgoInit1",
    "Body" : "AlgoBody6",
    "End"  : "AlgoEnd3"
}
```

This will load the RunType1 dll and chose these functions.

This could use a set of if / else statements

ie

```
if (initText == "AlgoInit1")
    callAlgoInit1();
else (initText == "AlgoInit2")
    callAlgoInit2();
```

etc

But this would fail if i wanted to add new algos to the library, without recoding this.

Is these a more elegant way of choosing or passing the functions to a generic run structure?

I would like to do something like:

```
runInitAlgo("AlgoInit1"); // take the actual parameter from the config
runBodyAlgo("AlgoBody6");
runEndAlgo("AlgoEnd3");
```

What is the best solution/patterns for achieving this in C#? So I dont have to hard-code the algo function names into the body of the application.

Thanks.

Comment: if your method in library do not take any parameters then you can easily use reflection to call all that (doable with parameter but more complex). With reflection you can invoke an method from it's string name but the project still need reference to those DLL obviously otherwise it wouldn't be able to do it's magic

Comment: @Franck, you don't need to reference the dll in the project if you also dynamically load the dll.

Comment: yes the reflection solution is the kind of thing i had in mind. Will look into this, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<string, Action>actions = new Dictionary<string, Action>();

void Init(){
  actions.Add("Init" ,AlgoInit1);
  actions.Add("Body" ,AlgoBody6);
  actions.Add("End" ,AlgoEnd3);
}

void Do(string action){
   actions[action]();
}

private static void AlgoInit1(){
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

You dictionary can be a static or a member field in your class.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but how do i define the Actions dynamically? If i don't already know the function names.

Comment: At least you know what functions are available at compile item. And you can always remove items and add new mappings in you dictionary.

Comment: The idea is i can swap out the dll and specify new functions in the config. Some kind of hybrid of this with @Hybris95 suggestion of GetMethod seems like the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

If the name corresponds to a DLL, you can use that kind of logic to load dynamically your DLL and then the corresponding class (which inherits from a known interface known for example "Algo") :

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom("RunType1.dll");
Type dllType = assembly.GetType("RunType1.Algo");
Algo obj = Activator.CreateInstance(dllType) as Algo;
obj.Init();
obj.Body();
obj.End();
```

References :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx
[fr]http://populnet.blogspot.fr/2008/12/charger-une-dll-dynamiquement.html

Comment: Maybe check that if the obj is null or not.

Comment: Sure do the required checks ;) This is just showing the general principle if everything goes well.

Comment: This is my current solution, to generate a different dll for each Init type, but for more flexibility I would like to specify different init/body/end etc functions within the dll from the json.

Comment: This may help you if you wish to use a named method name : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.type.getmethod.aspx

Comment: Then you can use this from MethodInfo : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/hh194402.aspx

Comment: GetMethod/MethodInfo sounds perfect, will look at this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should work around the Strategy Pattern ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern ) which is more or less what you want to do.

For a basic C# implementation of the Strategy Pattern you can refer to this document:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/346873/Understanding-and-Implementing-the-Strategy-Patter

Comment: Yes, thanks, like the Strategy pattern, but I would like to use some more modern techniques than this example. I think his implementation is pretty much as my if/else example.